# Google My Business Requested entity was not found

Tags: google-my-business-api

I'm trying to implement an integration between a ERP system and Google My Business to keep store data in sync.

I have a project in the developer console. I have gained access to the GMB API and is approved by Google to use this API.

I'm using a serviceaccount and have followed the instructions from various guides.

But now I'm stuck.

I'm using the google GMB c# library to connect to GMB. I have a valid .12 file for my service account.

```
string MybusinessServiceScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage";
        String serviceAccountEmail = "myserviceaccount@myapplication-1349.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(_serviceP12File, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { MybusinessServiceScope },
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        return new MybusinessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
           {
               HttpClientInitializer = credential,
               ApplicationName = "myapplication-1349",
           });
```

When I try to List, Patch or Create locations I keep getting the same response:

Requested entity was not found. [404]

```
Errors [

Message[Requested entity was not found.] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]

]
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to make this work with a service account. After talking to google support on the matter I change to use the OAuth application flow instead.

This works.

My chat with google: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-My-Business-API/Unable-to-PATCH-location-with-v3/td-p/579536#

Hope this can help others

Answer (score 1):

this error occurs when the user doesn't have access to the provided location. (invalid access token or user access has been revoked etc)